# Horizontal and Vertical Analysis Financial Statement Formatting

Tags: tables, hline

I am working creating a horizontal and vertical analysis chart. For the sake of demonstration, here are my minimal working examples:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}    
    Horizontal analysis:
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l c c c c}
            & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Increase (Decrease)}\\ \cline{4-5}
            & FY 2022 & FY 2021 & \$ Amount & Percent\\
            Total Current Assets & & & &\\
            Net Plant, Property, and Equipment & & & &\\
            Total Assets & & & &\\
            Total Current Liabilities & & & &\\
            Total Liabilities & & & &\\
            Total Stockholders' Equity & & & &
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    Vertical analysis:
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l c c c c}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{FY 2022}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{FY 2021}\\ \cline{2-5}
            & \$ Amount & Percent & \$ Amount & Percent\\
            Total Revenue & & & &\\
            Total Cost of Goods Sold & & & &\\
            Gross Profit & & & &\\
            Operating Expenses & & & &\\
            Operating Income & & & &\\
            Income Tax Expense & & & &\\
            Net Income & & & &
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: current output]

Desired horizontal analysis:
[image: desired horizontal analysis]

Desired vertical analysis:
[image]

I have managed to get the top horizontal lines as circled in blue. Can someone help out on how to draw the horizontal lines with breaks as indicated by red arrows and circles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be done with additional columns:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}    
    Horizontal analysis:
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c c}
            & & & & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Increase (Decrease)} \\ \cline{6-8}
            & FY 2022 & & FY 2021 & & \$ Amount & & Percent \\ \hhline{~-~-~-~-}
            Total Current Assets               & 200 & & 100 & & 100 & & 50 \\
            Net Plant, Property, and Equipment & 200 & & 100 & & 100 & & 50 \\
            Total Assets                       & 200 & & 100 & & 100 & & 50 \\
            Total Current Liabilities          & 200 & & 100 & & 100 & & 50 \\
            Total Liabilities                  & 200 & & 100 & & 100 & & 50 \\
            Total Stockholders' Equity         & 200 & & 100 & & 100 & & 50 \\ \hhline{~=~=~=~=}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    Vertical analysis:
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l c c c p{5mm} c c c}
            & \multicolumn{3}{c}{FY 2022} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{FY 2021} \\ \cline{2-4}\cline{6-8}
            & \$ Amount & & Percent & & \$ Amount & & Percent \\ \hhline{~-~-~-~-}
            Total Revenue            & 200 & & 100 & & 100 & & 50 \\
            Total Cost of Goods Sold & 200 & & 100 & & 100 & & 50 \\
            Gross Profit             & 200 & & 100 & & 100 & & 50 \\
            Operating Expenses       & 200 & & 100 & & 100 & & 50 \\
            Operating Income         & 200 & & 100 & & 100 & & 50 \\
            Income Tax Expense       & 200 & & 100 & & 100 & & 50 \\
            Net Income               & 200 & & 100 & & 100 & & 50 \\ \hhline{~=~=~=~=}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could change the space between columns using columns of type `p{<some width>}`.

For double horizontal line `hhline` command from the package of the same name is used.

Comment: Looks like a good solution! Thank you!